Ubuntu 20.04 VMware Workstation Cannot Connect to Internet
I am a new user of Ubuntu 20.04, and I have it installed using VMWare Workstation. Recently I have been unable to connect to the internet within the VM. I've been trying several solutions, but none have seemed to resolve the issue. The primary issue seems to be this "ens33" connection, but I'm not sure how to fully resolve it. Here is the result I get when I check current IP addresses in the terminal:
jordandood@ubuntu:~$ ip a: 
1. lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:9e:ac:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s1

I've tried several things so far:

I have my network connection set to bridged for all my attempts to resolve the issue
I tried modifying /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml file directly, via these commands:

sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
sudo netplan apply
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

When I first opened the .yaml file, it showed
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager: .yaml file version 1
I modified it to then be this:
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
ens33:
dhcp4: true
renderer: NetworkManager
.yaml file version 2
I applied the changes, and restarted the network manager, but still no dice. I saw previous documentation regarding the editing of an "interface document," but I think that was for older versions of ubuntu and was replaced with the netplan file. Any suggestions for how I can get internet back online? I would prefer not to do a full reinstall of Ubuntu on my VM if I can help it.
